# What is this Groovy syntax called (Gradle 'exclude' closure syntax, e.g.)?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I feel like I've seen the term for this somewhere, but I haven't been able to find it on the web or SO.  What is the name for the Groovy syntax that makes it possible to append the closure after the `compile` method in a Gradle `dependencies` closure, for example?  How does it work?  How would I write a function that uses this syntax?

```
compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
  exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy has a flexible syntax for passing a closure as the last parameter to a method. Consider:

```
def myCompile (a, b, c) {
    println c(a,b)
}

myCompile(10, 20, { x, y -> x + y })

myCompile(10, 20) { x, y ->
    x + y
}
```

I don't think this has a name, but more generally the Gradle `build.gradle` syntax forms a [DSL](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html) (Domain Specific Language) which is fluid and natural. DSLs are the motivation for syntactic sugar such as this (and many other examples... it is a huge topic).

Comment: That's what it is!  I knew I had seen it before!  Thanks for a great answer!